# How to use JMockit to mock Groovy method that takes in a Closure parameter?

Tags: groovy, jmockit

I have the following code:

```
def method() {
    try {
        dependency0.call({ arg -> })
    } catch {
        dependency1.call()
    }
}
```

and the following test:

```
@Test
void shouldDoSomething(
        @Mocked final Dependency0 dependency0Mock) {
    final dependency1Mock = getDependency1Mock()

    new Expectations() {{
        dependency0Mock.call((Closure) any)
        result = new Exception('expected')

    final sut = new Sut(dependency1Mock, dependency0Mock)

    sut.method()
}
```

When the test runs, it emits the following exception:

```
mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Parameter "arg" of Dependency0#call(groovy.lang.Closure arg) expected null, got Sut$_method_closure1@cafebead
```

How do I go about mocking a method that takes in a Groovy Closure?

UPDATE: The same exception is thrown even if the argument type is `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JMockit. Rather, use map coercion as described at http://johnpwood.net/2008/06/13/overriding-java-methods-in-groovy-for-unit-testing/.

Comment: This does not work for constructors which takes argument as parameters. In that case mock/stubs from Groovy are not enough.